# Android Mediaplayer gives error while it is trying to play mp4 file which is recorded by LIVE555 QuickPlayerFilesink

Tags: android-mediaplayer, live555, openrtsp

I am facing below error on Android Kitkat when I am trying to play recorded video which is recorded by LIVE555.

Following is my source code to play video on App:

```
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.setDataSource(filePath); <------ getting error here
        player.setDisplay(holder);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
        player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        log.debug("prepare async called");
        player.prepareAsync();
```

Error log is given below:

```
07-28 04:59:17.942 E/MediaPlayerService( 2242): error: -2147483648
07-28 04:59:17.942 E/MediaPlayer( 4072): Unable to create media player
07-28 04:59:17.942 W/RecordingActivity*( 4072): Failed to set file: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
```

Here Please note that: Same Android and Live555 source code is working on Android Gingerbread.

Comment: Path to the recorded MP4 file.

Comment: I understand that. I was asking what is the value you are assigning for filePath?

Comment: it is string. like "/mnt/sdcard/1-1234.mp4"